# Blocking or Disabling Airplay, Screen Mirror, Screen Cast, etc

Tags: video-streaming, drm

We are building a unique streaming app using React Native. We want to disable or stop airplay, screen cast or screen mirror functions alltogether due to the content rights and release window.

We've been able to disable screenshots and digital recoding e.g. Loom. However, we are not able to disable airplay or screen mirror.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully disable screen casting, screen mirror, smart view, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214257/how-to-fully-disable-screen-casting-screen-mirror-smart-view-etc)

Comment: no, that's the other question we submitted. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score -1):

There is an AVplayer property which has been exposed to React Native Video and which controls this. The property is 'allowsExternalPlayback'.

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the player allows switching to external playback mode.

(from the original apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387441-allowsexternalplayback)

The React Native Video documentation is here: https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#allowsexternalplayback

Note that there is an issue, or feature depending on how you look at it or who you talk to, that means this applies only to video - the audio can still be cast.